# How to infer property type of generic parameter and map to another type

Tags: typescript

`testFunc1` is using `SomeMapper` and getting the correct generic parameter.

In `testFunc2` below I try to use a mapped type as function argument, but for some reason the SomeMapper is getting the wrong generic parameter.

How can I get `{ name: 'match' }` as function argument for `listener`?

```
type SomeMapper<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 'A' extends T[K] ? 'match' : 'no-match' }

function testFunc1<T extends Record<string, { params: Record<string, string> }>>(
  args: T & { [K in keyof T]: { listener: SomeMapper<T[K]['params']> } }
) {}

const test1 = testFunc1({
  someEvent: {
    params: { name: 'A' as const },
    listener: { name: 'match' } // type mapping with SomeMapper works!
  }
})

function testFunc2<T extends Record<string, { params: Record<string, string> }>>(
  args: T & { [K in keyof T]: { listener: (args: SomeMapper<T[K]['params']>) => unknown } }
) {}

const test2 = testFunc2({
  someEvent: {
    params: { name: 'A' as const },
    listener: (args /* args = SomeMapper<Record<string, string>> */) => {
      // 'args' should be { name: 'match' }

      return
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible but I haven't spent a lot of time looking; you really want `args` to be contextually typed and the typing for the argument to `listener` should depend on `T` but not mess with the *inference* of `T`. That is, you want the `T` in `SomeMapper<T[K]['params']>` to be *non-inferential*.  But there's no official support for that and the workarounds don't work for this case, see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-520191642).  If someone finds a great solution I'm all ears; otherwise I might come back and write this up

Comment: You can have the compiler force you to write `listener: (args: { name: 'match' }) => { ... }` but I don't believe you can have it infer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this

```js
type SomeMapper<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 'A' extends T[K] ? 'match' : 'no-match' }

type ListenerDecl<T> = {
  params: T;
  listener: (args: SomeMapper<T>) => unknown
}

function testFunc2<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  args: { [K in keyof T]: ListenerDecl<T[K]> }
) { }


const test2 = testFunc2({
  someEvent: {
    params: { name: 'A' as const },
    listener: (args) => {
      // 'args' should be { name: 'match' }
      return
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type SomeMapper<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 'A' extends T[K] ? 'match' : 'no-match' }

function testFunc1<T extends Record<string, { params: Record<string, string> }>>(
  _args: T & { [K in keyof T]: { listener: SomeMapper<T[K]['params']> } }
) {}

const test1 = testFunc1({
  someEvent: {
    params: { name: 'A' as const },
    listener: { name: 'match' } // type mapping with SomeMapper works!
  }
})

function testFunc2<T extends Record<string, { params: Record<string, string> }>>(
  _args: T & { [K in keyof T]: { listener: (args: SomeMapper<T[K]['params']>) => unknown } }
) {}

const test2 = testFunc2({
  someEvent: {
    params: { name: 'A' as const },
    listener: (_args /* args = SomeMapper<Record<string, string>> */) => {
      // 'args' should be { name: 'match' }

      return
    }
  }
})
```

I tried this and it didnt have any errors whatsoever. If this worked then I am very happy for you.